# Anyone knows any "automatic" package to draw graphs of posets (the Hasse diagrams)?

Tags: graphics, packages, code

anyone knows any "automatic" package to draw graphs of posets (the Hasse diagrams)?
I know TikZ, but I wanted something faster (automatic).
Thank you.

Comment: Iirc sage can make those diagrams and export to tikz. It's no latex solution, but still considerably faster than making everything by hand.

Comment: what about `graphviz`?